# Shifting array to the right - homework

Tags: java, arrays

This is what I have so far, but when I run it, I get a Java mismatch error.
This is my array:

```
char[] letters = {'A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};


/********************************************************************************
    shiftRight() will move the contents of the array one slot to the right
********************************************************************************/
public static void shiftRight( char [] letters )
{
    char last = letters[letters.length-1];          // save off first element

    // shift right
    for( int index =letters.length-1; index >= 0 ; index-- )
        letters[index+1] = letters [index];

    // wrap last element into first slot
    letters[0] = last;
    System.out.print("\nshifted Array: " );
}
```

Comment: i have to shift everything to the right . the last character has to be inputed back into letters[0]

Comment: Use println() instead of print(\n)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
 public static void shiftRight( char [] letters )
    {

        char last = letters[letters.length-1];          // save off first element

        // shift right
        for( int index =letters.length-2; index >= 0 ; index-- )
            letters[index+1] = letters [index];

        // wrap last element into first slot
        letters[0] = last;
        System.out.print("\nshifted Array: " + Arrays.toString(letters) );

    }
```

I only modified your: `letters.length-1` into `letters.length-2` and printed the array.

Another, easier approach is to use, `System.arraycopy` like:

```
last = letters[letters.length-1];
System.arraycopy(letters, 0, letters, 1, letters.length-1 );
letters[0] = last;
```

To print the array you can also use:

```
System.out.print("{");
for (int i=0;i<letters.length-1;i++)
    System.out.print("'"+letters[i]+",");
System.out.println("'"+letters[letters.length-1]+"'}");
```

Comment: whats the -2 doing? nd array to string does what?

Comment: @javip is starting the index from the previous to the last element, since in his loop he is doing: `letters[index+1]` that should be the last element.

Comment: getting an error when it tries to make the array into a string

Comment: @javip What java version are you running? And what is the error? Arrays.toString should be available since 1.5 (java 5).

Comment: H:\My Documents\ArrayLab.java:131: error: method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
  System.out.print("\nshifted Array: " + letters.toString(letters) );
                                                ^
  required: no arguments
  found: char[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: @javip you need to use: `Arrays.toString(letters)` not `letters.toString(letters)`. Arrays is a class that knows how to work with arrays.

Comment: H:\My Documents\ArrayLab.java:134: error: method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.print("\nshifted Array: " + Arrays.toString(letters) );
                                                     ^
  required: no arguments
  found: char[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: @javip letters is the same: `char[] letters`, right? Is this happening in the same `shiftRight` function and you have imported: ` java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: @javip I have updated my answer, the last code, will print your array like an `Array.toString` call.

Comment: @javip Then you are not using one of my methods to shift the array

Answer (score 2):

When `letters[index+1]` is executed for the first time in the for-loop (when `index = letters.length-1`), it's pointing to `letters[letters.length]` which is not a valid index, since indexes go from `0` to `length-1`.

Update your for-loop to start `index` at `letters.length-2` and also make sure your `array.length>1`. That is to say:

```
   if(letters.length > 1){ //make sure array has minimum two elements
      // shift right
      for( int index = letters.length-2; index >= 0 ; index-- ){
          letters[index+1] = letters [index];
      }
   }
```

Also in the end, you may print the array as:

```
   System.out.println("Shifted Array: " +letters);
```

**EDIT:** Sample working code.

If you make the array as `Character` array  e.g. below in your `main` (this is required for assistance in printing ONLY)

```
    Character[] letters = {'A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
```

and then pass that to `shiftRight` method with updated code as below:

```
  public static void shiftRight( Character [] letters )
  {
    Character last = letters[letters.length-1];  
    if(letters.length >1){ //make sure array has minimum two elements
        // shift right
        for( int index =letters.length-2; index >= 0 ; index-- ){
            letters[index+1] = letters [index];
        }
     }
    letters[0] = last;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
    //^ prints: Shifted Array: [J, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]
  }
```

You should be all set.

Comment: it prints out some weird characters

Comment: @javip Can you please share your letters array? Also let me know, what is it printing? I added a sample code which seems to working. Please check.

Comment: char[]letters = {'A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};

this is whats printing[C@eb017e

Comment: hmm does that print all of the letters shifted?

Comment: @javip: I used the sample code as in my answer, and it prints `Shifted Array: JABCDEFGHI`. Try printing one char at a time as : `for(char c: letters){ System.out.println(String.valueOf(c));}`.

Comment: print out should look like this  'J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','I'

Comment: hmm i dont get why are there characters in char[] letters = {'a','b', 'c'};

Comment: @javip That was just a sample code. Now I replaced with your original letters. Give me a minute, I will share the printing code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18749/discussion-between-yogendra-singh-and-javip)

Comment: well thats weird its still printing out  the same weird charactrs the array char[letters] is already defined in main

Comment: @javip: I updated the answer. Please check if that helps. If you don't like `Character[]` then I think you need to manually print your result in the desired format. Please note: I am using Java 7. Which version are you using?

Comment: do i  have to import something because its giving me an erro

Comment: H:\My Documents\ArrayLab.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
     System.out.println(Arrays.asList(letters));
                              ^
  symbol:   method asList(char[])
  location: class Arrays
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: @javip Did you add the import statement `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 0):

add

```
     if(index<letters.length-1)  condition
```

inside your for loop before

```
 letters[index+1] = letters [index]
```

if you don't check `if(index<letters.length-1)` condition you'd get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception at your last inddex here `letters[index+1] = letters [index]`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you obtain an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as soon as you want to read (within the loop):

```
letters[index+1]
```

The cause is the your `index` variable initialization: `index = letters.length-1`

So `letters[index+1] == letters[letters.length]`   but logically `letters.length` leads to   `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

A simple way to correct your code without changing your logic:

```
for(int index = letters.length-1; index > 0 ; index--)
   letters[index] = letters [index-1];
```

Notice the operator sign `>` instead of `>=`. Otherwise, this would also lead to the same `Exception`.

Furthermore, in order to display the final array, use: `Arrays.toString(letters)`

I've even written my solution keeping your logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] letters = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
    printShiftedLetters(shiftElementsToRight(letters));
}

public static char[] shiftElementsToRight(char[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("array must not be null");
    }
    if(array.length <= 1){
        return array;
    }
    char[] shiftedArray = new char[array.length];
    char lastElement = array[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        shiftedArray[i] = array[i - 1];
    }
    shiftedArray[0] = lastElement;
    return shiftedArray;
}

private static void printShiftedLetters(char[] shiftedLetters) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shiftedLetters));
}
```

Comment: @javip Is that exactly what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

### For integer Values

You can do something like for integer values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    arrayReorder(arr,25);
}



private static void arrayReorder(int[] arr, int repeat) {
    int count = 0;
    int length = arr.length;
    int end = 0;
    int traversedArray[] = new int[length];

    while (count < repeat) {
        end = arr[length-1];
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            traversedArray[i] = arr[i-1];
            traversedArray[0] = end;
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int a : traversedArray) {
            System.out.print(a + " -> ");
        }
        arr = traversedArray.clone();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me.

```
   public void rightShiftArray(int[] arr, int n){
        int[] output=new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int newLocation = (i+(arr.length+n))%arr.length;
            output[newLocation] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(output[i]+",");
        }
    }
```

arr -> Array to be shifted       n   -> Shift the element by how many position.