# How to shift element in an Arraylist to the right in java

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am trying to create a method that shifts all of the elements in an arraylist to the right and the last element will become the first element. When I run the code, I am told I have an out of bounds error. Here is what I have so far:

```
public void shiftRight() 
{
    //make temp variable to hold last element
    int temp = listValues.get(listValues.size()-1); 

    //make a loop to run through the array list
    for(int i = listValues.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //set the last element to the value of the 2nd to last element
        listValues.set(listValues.get(i),listValues.get(i-1)); 

        //set the first element to be the last element
        listValues.set(0, temp); 
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129043/shifting-array-to-the-right-homework) may help you..

Comment: So you want to do a circular rotation of the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems here:

1. Your for loop condition needs to exclude the zeroth element so it should be `i > 0` otherwise you'll get to the point where you want to put element at position `-1` to position `0` resulting in out of bounds error.
2. Setting the first element to be the last should be outside the loop.
3. [`listValues.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set) takes in an index in the list as the first parameter, you are giving it the object in the list

   ```
   public void shiftRight() 
   {
       //make temp variable to hold last element
       int temp = listValues.get(listValues.size()-1); 

       //make a loop to run through the array list
       for(int i = listValues.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
       {
           //set the last element to the value of the 2nd to last element
           listValues.set(i,listValues.get(i-1)); 
       }
       //set the first element to be the last element
       listValues.set(0, temp);     
   }
   ```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this is an exercise you are working on, but the [ArrayList.add(int index,E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) method does almost what you want.

"Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. *Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right* (adds one to their indices)."  (italics added)

So just add the last element in the list at position 0.  And delete it from the end.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and shortest solution : (if you **don't have concurrent use of list** - Because in concurrent use and iterating on it, the **list size** should not change, otherwise you get **ConcurrentModificationException**)

```
public void shiftOneToRight() {
    
    listValues.add(0, listValues.remove(listValues.size() - 1));
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest solution

> Collections.rotate(list, rotationPosition);

Answer (score 0):

```
my code to put a number in the right place in a List

            int nr = 5;  // just a test number
            boolean foundPlace = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < integerList.size(); i++){

                if(nr <= integerList.get(i)){
                    integerList.add(i,nr);
                    foundPlace = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (!foundPlace)
                integerList.add(integerList.size(), nr);
```

as the guy above said, "integerList.add(element)" inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently...

Answer (score 0):

input array list: *locationMap*

shift LHS elements from *idxStart* in circular way

shifted output list: *extendedList*

```
// make extended list to behave like circular
List<String> extendedList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = idxStart; i < locationMap.size(); i++) { // current to end
    extendedList.add(locationMap.get(i));
}
for (int i = 0; i < idxStart; i++) { // 0 to current
    extendedList.add(locationMap.get(i));
}
```